# Does AChartEngine support real-time values adding and x-scrolling

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

In order to display real-time digital input/output value like oscilloscope

Comment: i've found series.add(x,y) method. How can x-scrolling be done?

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to do x-scrolling, but you can create your own to do this. This is an example.

```
    for (int i = values.getItemCount() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        values.add(i + 1, value.getY(i));
    }
    values.add(0, y);
```

"values" is a TimeSeries.

Basically I swap penultimate value to the last value, and so on. I add, finally, the new value in position 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
mSeries.add(++xCounter, aData);
        if (mChartView != null) {
            if (mSeries.getItemCount() >= 200) {
                mSeries.remove(0);
            }
            mhartView.repaint();
        }
```

can help here to draw dynamic view. 200 is your view buffer size, so once it get filled it start to remove from top and add new value at tail.